# Displaying Average of 3 Different Columns in Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read three columns in an array, and average them. Example of array:

```
1095       10.40  13.65  9.11
```

Needed output:

```
Home ID#   Size1  Size2  Size3 Average
1095       10.40  13.65  9.11  11.05
```

I have gotten as far as the following in my code:

```
static void DisplayAverageSizes(double[,] roomsArray)
        {

            const int SCORESROWS = 7;
            const int SCORESCOLS = 4;
            uint[] scoresRowTotal = new uint[SCORESROWS];
            uint[] scoresColTotal = new uint[SCORESCOLS];
            uint[,] scores = new uint[,] { };

            for (int i=0; i<SCORESROWS; i++)
                for (int j=0; j<SCORESCOLS; j++)
                {
                    scoresRowTotal[i] += scores[i, j];
                    scoresColTotal[j] += scores[i, j];
                }
            for (int i = 0; i < SCORESROWS; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < SCORESCOLS; j++)
                    Console.Write("{0,9} ", scores[i, j]);
                Console.WriteLine("{0,9}", scoresRowTotal[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < SCORESCOLS -1; j++)
                Console.Write("{0,9} ", scoresColTotal[j]);
```

The error I am getting is:

Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. On line 93 it is referencing (Double[,] roomsArray). Since the input is in double format, for example Size1 being 10.41 this would be a double floating if I'm not mistaken. Or I would need to use a .ConvertTo() to process the request. Either way in the end I am needing to display my sample output.

Thanks,
J

Comment: As a side not, I am not sure if I need to list the column ID's on this line or not.

    uint[,] scores = new uint[,] { **list array ID's here** };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown when you attempt to access an element of an array that doesn't exist.

Note that you have initialized scores as follows:

```
uint[,] scores = new uint[,] { };
```

This creates an empty two-dimensional array of unsigned integers. But then, you reference it as follows:

```
scoresRowTotal[i] += scores[i, j];
```

Make sure you put something in the array before you try to use it:

```
uint[,] scores = new uint[,] { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };
```

**UPDATE**

What I showed you was *array initializer* syntax. Essentially, the array appears in memory like this:

```
[0] [1]
[2] [3]
```

So that item at row 0, column 0 has the value 0, and item at row 1, column 1 has the value 3.

You can nest these as deeply as you need to, though they get kind of difficult to maintain at that point. (Not to mention, difficult to diagram.)

Comment: When I add a value to the array { {0,1}, {2,3} }; is this selecting the columns within the array? For example if I want to calculate the average of row 1, but for the values of column 1,2 etc. Would that be where the values of the array come in? I guess I am lost there. What values to add so my calculation will work. Thanks.